# S3 bucket size for subset bucket names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How can I use a custom list of S3 bucket names from  local file as sometimes it takes too long for large buckets or different storage class. not sure sometimes it doesn't show all S3 buckets?

```py
with open('subsetbucketslist.txt') as f:
    allbuckets = f.read().splitlines()
```

How to use local file of buckets names as input?

By default it would list all buckets:

```py
import boto3

total_size = 0
s3=boto3.resource('s3')

for mybucket in s3.buckets.all():
    mybucket_size=sum([object.size for object in boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(mybucket.name).objects.all()])
    print (mybucket.name, mybucket_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the size for particular buckets, then put those bucket names in your `for` loop:

```py
import boto3

total_size = 0
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

with open('subsetbucketslist.txt') as f:
    allbuckets = f.read().splitlines()

for bucket_name in allbuckets:
    mybucket_size = sum([object.size for object in boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).objects.all()])
    print (bucket_name, mybucket_size)
```

It's also worth mentioning that Amazon CloudWatch keeps track of bucket sizes (`BucketSizeBytes`). See: [Metrics and dimensions - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html)

Comment: John have you tested it works ?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subset-s3-size.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (mybucket.name, mybucket_size)
NameError: name 'mybucket' is not defined

also tried changed mybucket.name to bucket_name.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subset-s3-size.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (bucket_name.name, mybucket_size)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I fixed the `bucket_name` in the last line. No, I didn't test it -- I mostly just took your code and made some small changes.

Comment: tested the update and it worked